# Implement wait-notify on database level to handle deadlocks

Tags: java, database, multithreading, semaphore

### Background

I've multiple application servers running the same application which points to single database server.

Sometimes, `n` users do the same function on `n` application servers, which goes to the single database server and deadlock happened (as here [Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840837))  causing `m` transactions rolled-back (where 1 < `m` < `n`).

We solve this problem on a single Application Server machine, by synchronising the call to the service method (using `synchronized` keyword,  So only one thread at a time can access the database.

But this solution doesn't work on multiple app servers (our case here).

### The question

Can we implement some mechanism (e.g. db semaphore), so we can make one caller execute a transaction at a time, and for the other callers to wait until the first one finish, then another one to 
acquire the lock and so on.

Comment: Yes, creating a semaphore in the database is perfectly feasible. Whether it's a good idea in practice depends very much on the use case. Here's an example: http://blog.udby.com/archives/14

Comment: FYI - The synchronized / semaphore approach is known as pessimistic locking. Have you considered [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

Comment: @LanceJava, does `pestimistc locking` grantees all transactions wait each other until all executed at the end?

Comment: @LanceJava The existing system sounds like it already uses optimistic locking, but it sounds like that's not satisfactory because of heavy contention for the database.

Comment: @james large Yes, the isolation level is read_committed, which i believe it casues the deadlocks ( vs pesimistic lock which prevent two callers from obtaining the lock), but what will happen with the other callers in pestimistic locking? As what we want achieve here is waiting, not canceling the other callers/tnxs.

Comment: Well, if your database is unable to keep up with the volume of updates, then that's a problem that you won't be able to fix by tinkering with the locking strategy.  You will have to scale up.

Comment: @jameslarge - I disagree, the existing system is using pessimistic locking by the sounds of it. But the question is asking how to share the lock across two (or more jvm's). I was suggesting optimistic locking which is a totally different approach. Good for scenarios where contention occurs rarely. Instead of locking, you check a condition and rollback / retry if the check fails.

Comment: Currently, on db leve we use optimistic locking, while in application level we use pestimistic, whuch totaly is optimistic because of the db